# Ionic Native Email Composer - Passing ngModel as array

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic's Email Composer Plugin and want to take inputs from a page and pass them as an array into the email so that multiple users can be emailed at once. Currently, only the first email entered is being passed, not all of them.

The HTML is:

```
<ion-content>

   <ion-item id="row" *ngFor="let emailinput of emailinputs ; let i = index">
      <ion-label fixed id="label">
        Email
      </ion-label>
         <ion-input type="email" id="email" placeholder="jdoe@gmail.com" (keyup.enter)="Send($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="emailinputs[i].email"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>

   <div padding>
      <button (click) = "addnewemail()" id="register" ion-button full color="nudgetprim" block>Add</button>
      <button (click) = "sendinvite(emailinputs.email)" id="register" ion-button full color="nudgetprim" block>Invite</button>
   </div>

</ion-content>
```

The Typescript is:

```
sendinvite() {
      var bcc = [];
      for(var e in this.emailinputs){
      if (this.emailinputs[e].email==null || this.emailinputs[e].email=="" || !this.emailinputs[e].email.includes("@") || !this.emailinputs[e].email.includes("."))
        {
          let alert = this.alerCtrl.create({
                title: 'Error!',
                message: 'There was an error with an email address you entered.',
                buttons: ['Ok']
              });
              alert.present()
            }
      else {
      bcc.push(this.emailinputs[e].email);
      this.emailComposer.isAvailable().then((available: boolean) =>{
       if(available) {
         //Now we know we can send
       }
      });

      let email = {
        // to: this.emailVal,
        // cc: 'erika@mustermann.de',
        bcc: bcc,
        attachments: [
          'file://img/logo.png',
          'res://icon.png',
          'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...',
          'file://README.pdf'
        ],
        subject: 'Nudget Invite',
        body: '<a href="">Join my grocery list!</a>',
        isHtml: true
      };

      // Send a text message using default options
      this.emailComposer.open(email);        }}
    }
```

bcc is not being populated properly. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To property supports strings. You have to convert array to strings.

You can convert this way.

```
const emailVal = ['aa@aa.com', 'bb@aa.com'];
let emailTo = '';
emailVal.map((email, index) => {
    console.log(email, index)
    if (index === emailVal.length - 1) {
      emailTo = emailTo + email;
    } else {
        emailTo = emailTo + email + ', ';
    }
});

console.log(emailTo);

// result
// "aa@aa.com, bb@aa.com"
```